# Windows 8: Activating an app using Background task

Tags: windows, winapi

I am doing a windows 8 App using c#. the app goes to suspend state if its inactive, I am trying to bring the app to front based on external events. So I used a background task with this app which monitors the external event. Once the event occurs I am able to send updates to the app but not able to bring it to front. any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: That's not possible.  Consider a live tile.